# Proving NP-completeness for a problem is a generalization of a known NP-complete problem

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, np-complete

For example, the List Coloring Problem (LCP) is a generalization of Graph Coloring Problem (GCP). As known, given graph $G(V,E)$ and an integer $k \leq |V|$, the question that whether $G$ is $k$-colorable in GCP is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete.

Since LCP is a generalization of GCP, can I say the decision question that whether $G$ is $k$-colorable in LCP is also $\mathcal{NP}$-complete? Is it necessary to prove by strict reduction?

Thanks a lot if someone can give any answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does it mean for one problem to be a generalization of another? It means that there is an easy reduction from the latter to the former.

In your case, LCP is a generalization of GCP, and so there should be an easy reduction from GCP to LCP: Given an instance $(G,k)$ of GCP, construct an instance of LCP by taking $G$ and giving each vertex the list $\{1,\ldots,k\}$. The new problem is completely equivalent to the original one. This is a polytime reduction, and so since GCP is NP-hard, so is LCP.

In order to show that LCP is actually NP-complete, you need to show that it is in NP. Here the reduction is of no help, and you have to prove it directly. But this is easy – the witness is a valid list coloring, which is easily checkable in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks again! But what if the LCP is restricted by some constraint such as each color has a capacity, i.e., the maximum number of times it can be used in $G$. Do I necessarily to prove this problem considering the capacity? Or ignore the capacity constraint during the reduction procedure.

Comment: In order to show that a problem is NP-hard, you have to reduce another NP-hard problem to it. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: So, does it mean that I have to reduce another NP-hard problem which includes corresponding capacity constraint to my problem?

Comment: In order to show that a problem is NP-hard, you have to reduce another NP-hard problem to it. Nothing more, nothing less. You work out what it implies in your case.

Comment: I am still confused. Can you explain more specifically? In my case, the color capacity is considered in LCP, but not in GCP. I don’t know if it will make any difference in reduction.

Comment: It shouldn’t. You could set the capacity to $n$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.